# How to view the functions of a loaded library in x64dbg

Tags: x64dbg, functions, libraries

I am working on a packed file with UPX.
In one of the lines it calls to the value of the address `0xF5222C` which is: `0x778057c0`.
[image]

The debugger auto-completes it to `kernel32.LoadLibraryA`.
Where can I verify that this is the address of the function?

I looked at the "Memory Map" tab but all I can see is the address (`0x777F000`) of the kernel32.dll module:
[image]

Is there a place I can view the addrresses of all the functions related to a specific module?

**EDIT:**
I tried `Search for > All Modules > Intermodlar calls`:
[image]

I searched for `LoadLibraryA` (address `0x778057c0`) but it doesn't find it:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either press Ctrl+G and type `LoadLibraryA` to land at this function address, or if you want to list all the functions from kernel32.dll you can go to the `Symbols` tab like this:

[image]

From there you can view the function address or just double-click "LoadLibraryA" to follow it in disassembler.